# Stating Python version in repository when using pyenv-virtualenv

Tags: python, version-control

I came to know about [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) and [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) a while ago, and used them separately for a while. Recently, while investigating best practices and tools for Python development I found [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv). I find it useful (it takes care of using the right method for creating the virtual environment depending on the Python version) and clean (since the `venv` directory is not entangled with your codebase).

The problem I find is that previously (when using `pyenv` and `virtualenv` separately) I would push my `requirements.txt` file and my `.python-version` file to the repository. When cloning the project a few months later I could recreate my virtual environment using `requirements.txt` and could check `.python-version` to see which Python version I was developing on.

With `pyenv-virtualenv`, however, the `.python-version` file is less useful. Since in `pyenv-virtualenv` a virtual environment is treated like a new version of Python inside `pyenv`, and the way to link your project to the virtual environment is by "setting the Python version" to that virtual environment, the file no longer contains the exact Python version you are using.

Let's pretend I'm working on project Euler and decide to create a virtual environment for it using `pyenv-virtualenv`, and I call it project_euler. In order to make my code base to run on that virtual environment I need to go to the project's directory and type: `pyenv local project_euler`.

Now everything works great locally, but when I push to my repository and grab it again in a few months, `.python-version` won't be too useful, since it will only say "project_euler". Furthermore, if the person who downloads the repository has a virtualenv named `project_euler` as well which is configured differently to the one I was using when I pushed, **they might use a wrongly-configured environment without realising it**. This wasn't a problem when using `pyenv` and `virtualenv` separately, since `.python-version` only included information about the Python version then, not the name of the virtual environment in use.

What are the best practices to deal with these issues? I can think of several options:

- Include the Python version in the name of your virtual environments: `project_euler_3.5.3` (note that this does not solve the issue with using the wrong virtual environment by mistake).
- Do not push `.python-version`, instead document the minimum supported Python version in the `README`.
- Do not push `.python-version`, and do not document the Python version (doesn't seem right, since there are retrocompatibility issues even between minor revisions --e.g. 3.5 vs 3.4-- so it shouldn't be up to the user to have to guess).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) for python development which solves a bunch of problems.

It is now the [official](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/#managing-dependencies) tool recommended from python.org

If you have experience with say npm or something like that, pipenv behaves in similar ways. It does its bookkeeping in two files (`Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`).It helps you to create *deterministic* builds. In order to get a working environment, you commit both as you would with a `requirements.txt` alongside your code, check out the code, run `pipenv install` and voilà. With `pipenv shell` you enter your virtual environment.

In your `Pipfile` is a section for the purpose of defining the required python version, e.g.

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that with pip/virtualenv you can't. Both assume a compatible Python runtime is installed (they are Python packages after all). Specifying the version in the README is the way to go with that.

You could look into writing a custom installation script, but that's what [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) is for. You can specify the required Python version with `python_requires` in setup.py. This will give a sensible error message if the required Python isn't present and has many ways to handle other custom install needs.

This may seem like yet another way to manage versions, but it is the Python standard and there are a lot of advantages, including years of community knowledge.